# Distinc Criteria Hibernate java

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Tenho o seguinte contexto:

```
class Entidade1
private Long id;
private int commentId;
private int userId;
```

---

```
class Entidade2
private Long id;
private String descricao;
```

-
Tenho a seguinte criteria

```
Criteria criteria = persistence.createCriteria(Entidade2.class);
criteria.add((Restrictions.eq("descricao", "Teste")));
```

E preciso fazer o seguinte. retornar todas as Entidades2 que satisfazem o sequinte filtro

`Entidade1.commentId != Entidade2.id` e `Entidade1.userId = 1`

Hoje eu estou fazendo dois `for` para resolver o problema porem não esta performático.

Comment: São entidades não relacionadas explicitamente (atributos anotados com ManyToOne, OneTOne, etc)?

Comment: Não tem relacionamento entre elas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi direito a sua pergunta.

Eu entedi isso:

```
SELECT distinct * FROM entidade2 e2
WHERE e2.id not in ( SELECT e1.commentId FROM entidade1 e1 WHERE e1.userId = 1 );
```

Usando HQL ficaria:

```
String hql = "select distinct e2 FROM Entidade2 e2 where e2.id not in ( " +
             "select e1.commentId from Entidade1 e1 WHERE e1.userId = 1 )";
Query q = persistence.createQuery( hql );
List<Entidade2> lista = query.list();
```

Usando criteria:

```
Criteria criteria1 = persistence.createCriteria(Entidade1.class);
criteria1.add( Restrictions.eq("userId", 1));
criteria1.setProjection(Projections.property("commentId"));
List<Integer> sub = criteria1.list();

Criteria criteria2 = persistence.createCriteria(Entidade2.class);
criteria2.add( Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("id", sub)) );
criteria2.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")));
List<Entidade2> lista = criteria2.list();
```

Era isso mesmo a pergunta?

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.